# Using a Javascript Date Selector in Qualtrics survey - carry date to the survey field

Tags: javascript, html, calendar, survey, qualtrics

I'm trying to input a date selector tool so that a survey respondent can input a date by clicking on the field, a calendar will pop up, they can select the date, and the date will be inputted to the Qualtrics question text box.

Qualtrics has their own calendar tool available, but the issue is that the calendar is always visible. I only want the calendar to be visible when they either click the text box itself or a calendar icon (either would be fine). Here's the Qualtrics code:

```
    Enter a date:
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/yui/2.9.0/build/calendar/assets/skins/sam/calendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/yui/2.9.0/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/yui/2.9.0/build/calendar/calendar-min.js"></script> <script>
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function ()
{
  var qid = this.questionId;
  var calid = qid + '_cal';
  var y = QBuilder('div');
  $(y).setStyle({clear:'both'});
  var d = QBuilder('div',{className:'yui-skin-sam'},[
    QBuilder('div', {id:calid}),
    y
  ]);

  var c = this.questionContainer;
  c = $(c).down('.QuestionText');
  c.appendChild(d);
  var cal1 = new YAHOO.widget.Calendar(calid); 
  cal1.render(); 
  var input = $('QR~' + qid);
  $(input).setStyle({marginTop: '20px',width: '150px'});
  var p =$(input).up();
  var x = QBuilder('div');
  $(x).setStyle({clear:'both'});
  p.insert(x,{position:'before'});
    cal1.selectEvent.subscribe(function(e,dates){
    var date = dates[0][0];
    if (date[1] < 10)
        date[1] = '0' + date[1];
    if (date[2] < 10)
        date[2] = '0' + date[2];
    input.value = date[1] +'-'+date[2]+'-'+date[0];
  })
});
</script>
```

Here's the calendar tool that I'd like to use, but I can't figure out how to get the date to feed into the Qualtrics field text box.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that in Qualtrics $ refers to prototypejs, not jQuery.  So, you need to do something like:

```
$j = jQuery.noconflict();
$j( function() {
    $j( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
} );
```

However, that may not work if the datepicker code is itself using $ to refer to jQuery.

I've used https://github.com/joshsalverda/datepickr successfully with Qualtrics.

EDIT:
To implement datepickr in Quatrics:

1. Add datepickr script to Qualtrics header (you can upload the file to Qualtrics then get the url of the file to add to the header in a script tag)
2. Add datepickr CSS to Qualtrics custom CSS
3. Add JavaScript to your question to add datepickr to an input element (e.g., datepickr($(this.questionId).down('.InputText')), {dateFormat: 'm/d/Y'});

Comment: hmmm, it seems the github link isn't working...do you mind relinking?

Comment: Just kidding! It's due to the DDOS attack this morning...I'll check back tomorrow

Comment: I have virtually no exp. with Javascript. Would you mind explaining some of your steps for implementing this in Qualtrics?

Comment: Hi T. Gibbons, I'm sorry but you're still at too high of a level for me. 

1. What do you mean by Qualtrics header? What is the datepickr script? I honestly don't know what any of this is. I have some experience in HTML, but that's about it.

2. Where is the custom CSS section? Is it specific to a single question?

Comment: Qualtrics header and custom CSS under Look&Feel/Advanced - they apply to entire survey. datepickr script you download form github at the url I gave.

Comment: Again, I'm unsure how to decipher these pieces from Github. Right now, I'm looking at the index.html file and see what looks like some HTML, some CSS, and some Javascript. Do I pull out these pieces separately and embed them into the sections you're talking about in Qualtrics?

Comment: In the src directory download the min.js file and the .css file. Upload the min.js file to Qualtrics.  Copy the contents of the .css file to your custom CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Add this JavaScript to the field to use a plain HTML date input (no jQuery required).

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    var textInputs = this.questionContainer.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
    if (typeof textInputs[0] !== 'undefined') {
        textInputs[0].type = 'date';
    }
});
```